# Wordpress YouTube shortcode will not embed url

Tags: php, wordpress

My goal is to embed three YouTube videos next to each other using the YouTube shortcode as described by Wordress here. https://en.support.wordpress.com/videos/youtube/ Please see these images that show how where I am using the shortcode, the result I am seeing, and for the php I use to execute the shortcode. https://i.stack.imgur.com/c56mP.jpg

**Shortcode (copy paste from support.wordpress.com)**

```
[youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Oh12ROTQCE ]
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();
      do_shortcode(the_content());
      } // end while
    } // end if
    ?>
```

Comment: You're in text mode. Use the embed code in visual mode. You should also now be able to just drop the URL alone in and WP will embed it.

Comment: Correct, however, if I do that, how am I supposed to change the height and width of the video?

Comment: Well yes, if you need to more than just embed then you'll probably need the shortcode.

Comment: Are you saying using the shortcode in the *visual* editor also doesn't work?

Comment: I'm saying the Youtube shortcode as described on support.wordpress.com does not work at all.

Comment: In the screenshot you posted you're adding the shortcode in the text editor. Have you tried switching to visual editor and inserting the shortcode?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both the visual, and text editor